# Linux account expiration

Tags: linux, rhel5

If I do (in rhel5):

```
useradd -m -e 2009-07-03 -c "Temp Account" tempuser
```

Will this account expire at the end of 2009-07-03 or at the beginning?

What if the user is still logged in? Is it kicked out?

Thanx for the great site!
CM

Comment: this was what i was afraid of...

now im wondering how to deal with temporary accounts to allow the user to operate accounts per example only for a week...

Comment: As long as you kill any open sessions a user may have that's probably enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Account will expire at the end of 2009-07-03.
2. Logged in user won't be kicked out. He won't be able to log in after he logout.

**UPD:** 
You can set TMOUT variable in ~/.bash_profile:

```
export TMOUT=3600
```

This will logout user if he is idle for an hour.

Comment: Just remember that the user can always change their own environment variables.

Comment: You are right. My solution works only if you want not to forget about opened shell.